# primefaces not working with eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces

i'm doing some stuff with primefaces om eclipse indigo, i made a dynamic web project and selects the project facets and included the primefaces jar `primefaces-3.5.jar` i made a new xhtml page and write some code to make a new menubar, these is the final page that i run :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<h:body> 
<h:form>

<p:growl id="messages"/>

<h3>Default Menubar</h3>
<p:menubar>
    <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <p:submenu label="New" icon="ui-icon-contact">
            <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Other" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:menuitem value="Open" url="#" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />
    </p:submenu>

    <p:submenu label="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
        <p:menuitem value="Undo" url="#" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e" />
        <p:menuitem value="Redo" url="#" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e" />
    </p:submenu>

    <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon-help">
        <p:menuitem value="Contents" url="#" />
        <p:submenu label="Search" icon="ui-icon-search">
            <p:submenu label="Text">
                <p:menuitem value="Workspace" url="#" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="File" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:submenu>

    <p:submenu label="Actions" icon="ui-icon-gear">
        <p:submenu label="Ajax" icon="ui-icon-refresh">
            <p:menuitem value="Save" actionListener="#{menuBean.save}" icon="ui-icon-disk" update="messages"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{menuBean.update}" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" update="messages"/>
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax" icon="ui-icon-newwin">
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{menuBean.delete}" icon="ui-icon-close" update="messages" ajax="false"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:submenu>

    <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-close" />

    <f:facet name="options">
        <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px"/>
        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
    </f:facet>
</p:menubar>
 </h:form>
 </h:body> 
 </html>
```

the output of the page is :Default Menubar 
Note i get these sample from the prime faces [tutorials page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf)

Comment: Whats issue you are getting you did not mentioned?

Comment: i said that the page only outputs "Default Menubar" and no menu bars appears as its shown on the primefaces tutorials

Comment: please see in the console its show any error (both server and browser console)

Comment: Ok do one thing comment whole code and just add a single Primefaces textbox only in the page and see if it rendered or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you didn't include the PrimeFaces JAR file properly in the webapp's runtime classpath.

Here are the steps (well, step), you need to perform in a *Dynamic Web Project* in Eclipse in order to include a 3rd party JAR file properly in webapp's runtime classpath.

1. Drop the JAR file straight in project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

That's all.

If you have ever fiddled around in project's *Build Path* properties in an attempt to achieve/fix it, then you need to make absolutely sure that you undo it all, or it may still cause conflicts/clashes.

Comment: Did you successfully complete a basic JSF tutorial / HelloWorld example? Are you able to get `<h:xxx>`, `<f:xxx>` and `<ui:xxx>` to work? Rightclick the page in browser and *View Source*. If they are still there (along with `<p:xxx>` tags), then it simply means that the request URL as you see in browser's address bar did not match the URL pattern as you've definied for the `FacesServlet`. It's the one responsible for performing all the JSF works of producing the desired HTML output.

Comment: your assumption was right, the jar file needs to be put in the lib folder of the WEB_INF it should work from the first time but the browser was caching